# BDD passing Recaptcha and null value - Best Practices

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I have two doubts about BDD with Cucumber related to best practices.

I have a page to automate user registration.

You enter your personal data, such as: name, email, and confirmation
After that you select the options of your interest of the site (there are 10 comboboxes, can be as many as you want).
Insert a recaptcha and send.

I need to validate all cases of success, as well as failure.

So, here are my questions:

1) Page with recaptcha.
Since it is not possible to automate a recaptcha and this step naturally comes into my test, should I make a scenario for invalid recaptcha validation?

2) Is there any clever way for me to write a scenario exploring all the possible combinations of site interest options?

In my page:
( ) Economy
( ) Education
( ) Sports
( ) Recreation
( ) Travels
( ) ...

I want to be able to submit the test several times by testing 1 option selected, 2 options, 3 options, ..., all options.
But I just want to do it if there is a lean way to do it.

In other words: In Scenario Outline examples can I pass a null value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with what Thomas mentioned on Captcha I would say that this is one of the few things which cannot be automated to test (except the negative path).

I also agree with Thomas that you should not want to test every single possibility of the options using executable specifications, but rather use integration testing or possible even unit testing if the architecture of this part of the code allows that.

As for an actual executable scenario in Gherkin format I see something like the following for this functionality:

```
Given Paul supplied the incorrect Captcha
When he wants to register himself
Then he should not be registered
```

- You can wonder whether we should use the implementation word Captcha in the scenario since it will be incorrect when we would substitute Captcha in our implementation for something else.

There could be a potential other scenario depending on whether or not someone is allowed to register when no options are selected:

```
Given Paul has not chosen any of the possible interest topics
When he wants to register himself
Then he should not be registered
```

- notice the reuse of the sentences for the when and then part to allow for less test code.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding captcha, I would probably verify that a broken captcha stops the user. Verifying the positive path is obviously hard since the captcha is there to stop bots and an automated verification is the same as a bot.

Regarding verifying all your options, I would see if I could do that below the surface. Doing this from the UI using a browser is slow and you are talking about 2^10 combinations. That's a lot of cases. If all combinations needs to be tested, test them against the controller instead. This is a case where a tool like Cucumber may not be your best option. A programming language may be better than Gherkin.

If you still want to use Cucumber, at least make it fast and avoid the browser. I wrote a [blogpost](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2016/07/25/the-right-tool-for-the-job) about the right tool for the job. It might help you to understand why you don't have to go through to UI for all scenarios.